Finger joints in thicker stock
I am trying to cut finger joints in a 1 1/2 inch thick stock. My current jig does not allow for wood this thick. Are there any jigs that can accommodate this thickness or is there a way of using a Leigh jig and reversing the piece to cut from the other side as well?

Just checking, is it a requirement that the joint is cut using machines and jigs (as opposed to hand tools)? And do you have a table saw at your disposal or just a router?

Hi, welcome to StackExchange. I'm a little confused here, as most of the jigs that I know of for cutting box/finger joints allow for stock of any thickness, because they're all built on the same principle (regardless if built for TS or router). Surely the most cursory search for box-joint jigs would bring up not just one but multiple jigs of this sort?

Two follow-on questions occur to me, first about that thickness — is there a particular reason you must use wood this thick for the project? 1.5" is immensely thick stock for any conventional box even full-size chests or crates, often built from much thinner stock only using pine/another softwood. Are you just stuck with 6/4 stock you have on hand and don't want to waste away additional thickness or can't or don't want to resaw? Second, are box joints a must? Is another joint feasible for the project? Others that could work include reinforced mitres, semi-rebate joint + dowels (pinned rabbet)?

@Graphus - cursory search for box-joint jigs is not likely to find an answer for this question.  My cursory search did not give any insight on this question.  My Leigh jig does many good joints but this is beyond it.  My tenoning jig would work, awkward but OK up to about 5.25 inches across - (a US 2x6).  This is a good question.  I was hoping when I looked at this list this morning you'd have left some useful suggestions, maybe an answer.. I was also disappointed to find someone had downvoted the question.

This question is similar to: Finger Joints on a 2x10. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@quill, yes actually if the right terms are used it is 'likely'. As I said in my Comment most built box-joint jigs can accommodate stock of literally any thickness because of the way they work. Hence it is inevitable such jigs come up in a search. You'll notice also I used a question mark..... the sideline point I was making to the OP is that, as far as we can see, no research at all was done yadda yadda. Hal, if you're reading this a good stab as finding the answer for yourself prior to asking a Q is a requirement of the SE model.

Finding the right term for a 'likely' search is a matter of individual perception.  If we knew what to look for, it would be easy HOWEVER, we all have different points of view AND only after reading previous comments might someone develop a different idea/suggestion.  My next comment is such an idea that only came after pondering this issue for awhile

At first glance, thick board finger joints seems unusual.  It does however resemble something else.  A finger like joint might be used to make an (almost) all-wooden hinge type joint.  Specifically the term "wooden hinge" comes to mind. Two differences 1) some degree of rounding the finger edges 2) no glue

@quill, ignoring the didactic point I was making to the OP there's no point in trying to debate the search aspect on the merits! I just tried the most obvious search on the subject imaginable: box joint jig with no quotes. And all four of the top returns on Google are to videos showcasing jigs of the sort I mentioned, with five more below that....... So it is not a matter of interpretation or semantics, a most cursory search for box-joint jigs WILL bring up multiple jigs that are a solution to the problem.

I am assuming your jig looks like this, and that your problem is that the prongs are not long enough to route the joints:

(Note that presenting the face, rather than the end, of the board to the prongs does not help, because you still need to cut deep enough to accommodate the mating board’s thickness.)
Option 1
Cut as far as the jig allows, then reverse the board and manually align the cutaways with the prongs, as you suggest. I have not used this jig, but it’s possible that the onboard clamp does not open wide enough. In that case you need to use your own clamps.
Option 2
Cut as far as the jig allows, then put the board on its face and finish the cut with a long template router bit (top bearing), using each cutaway as a template. Square the rounded corners with a chisel, or do another pass with a shorter template bit, this time with the base of the router on the end of the board.
Option 3
If you have a table saw, a cross-cut sled where the board is held vertically should allow for stock thickness as large as your blade can protrude, minus the thickness of the sled. (A dado stack, if legal in your country, can speed things up.) There are many YouTube videos showing this technique.
Option 4
Mark and cut everything by hand. Since the hand saw does not care about angles, you might as well make the walls slanted to get dovetails 

For finger joints in thicker stock, you could definitely try flipping the piece and cutting from both sides if your jig doesn't accommodate the full thickness. Just make sure to align everything perfectly to avoid any mismatch. As for jigs, there are adjustable ones like the Leigh FMT or similar box joint jigs that can handle thicker stock with a bit of tweaking. You could also consider building a custom jig that allows for deeper cuts. It's all about precision!
